# Problem in parameterizing a CVXPY program

Tags: convex-optimization, cvx, cvxpy

I am trying to parameterize a CVXPY program as I need to repeatedly solve the problem, but I noticed that when my parameters are complex numbers, CVXPY models the problem in each iteration. For example, suppose I want to solve the following problem:

$$
\underset{\mathbf x}{\text{minimize}} | \mathbf A \mathbf x - \mathbf b| +  |\boldsymbol{\gamma} \mathbf x|, 
$$
where $\mathbf A \in \mathbb C^{3\times 4}$, $\mathbf x \in \mathbb C^{4 \times 1}$, $\mathbf b \in \mathbb C^{3 \times 1}$, and $\boldsymbol{\gamma} \in \mathbb C^{1 \times 4}$.

**I don't need to solve this problem repeatedly, but I am forcefully doing so to check whether I can consider $\boldsymbol \gamma$ as a parameter or not?**

Below is the code:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np


m = 4
n = 3
A = np.random.randn(n,m)+1j*np.random.randn(n,m)
b = np.random.randn(n)+1j*np.random.randn(n)

x = cp.Variable((m,),complex=True)
gamma = cp.Parameter((1,m),complex=True)
obj = cp.norm(A@x-b)+cp.abs(gamma@x)
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj))

for iIter in range(5):    
    gamma.value = np.random.randn(1,m)+1j*np.random.randn(1,m)
    prob.solve(verbose=True)
```

What I see from verbose is that CVXPY first models my problem in each iteration and then solves it. On the other hand, if I assume $\boldsymbol \gamma \in \mathbb R^{1\times 4}$, it **bypasses** the modeling from the next iteration. Why is this so? Are we not allowed to create complex-valued parameters?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but have you tried "You can check whether an expression or problem is DPP-compliant by calling the is_dcp method with the keyword argument dpp=True (by default, this keyword argument is False). "?  https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html "The DPP ruleset"

Comment: It is DPP-compliant. Just checked ```print(obj.is_dcp(dpp=True))```, and it returns True!

Comment: You should post a description and link to this question on the cvxpy GitHub issues page.